# Calling a column name based on a different columns values?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, data-science, data-analysis

I want to very simply call a column in a df based on a different columns value.

Below is what I would use, but how can I add another method on top of this that says give me all the values in a column called minutes or ***df['minutes']*** if another called ***column_name*** is a specific value?

```
df.loc[df['column_name'] == some_value]
```

Sample Data:

```
column_name | Minutes
   1-5           19
   6-10          22
   11-15          8
   1-5           11
   6-10          33
```

I want to filter for column_name = any value in that column and return all values under the minutes column.

so if column_name is 1-5 return all values in Minutes column

Comment: `df.loc[df['column_name'] == some_value,'minutes']` ?? if not , please add an example to clarify the question

Comment: Please explain your problem with a help of sample data and desired output.

Comment: Added some sample data with desired output - sorry @anky_91

Comment: @Chris90 , `df.loc[df['column_name'] == '1-5','Minutes']`  same as by previous comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A DataFrame usually contains **multiple** rows (and columns).

So if you ask whether particular column (say *xx*) has some value:

```
df.xx == 20
```

you will get a **boolean Series** with:

- indices copied from *df*,
- value stating whether *xx* column **in this row** *== 20*.

So I assume that you question about particular value in a given column
should actually be expressed as: *Does **any** element in this column
have particular value?*.

You can check it with *any()* function:

```
(df.xx == 22).any()
```

This time the result will be a **single** *boolean*.

In your case you can write:

```
if (df.column_name == '1-5').any():
    result = df.Minutes
```

Of course it is open to question *what if not*?
Do you want **another** column in *result* variable?

Another approach is to set the column name in some variable,
say *src_col*, based on some your logic.

Then, having this variable set, you can refer to the required column as:

```
result = df[src_col]
```

Note that this time:

- the column name is between brackets,
- but it is **not** surrounded with apostrophes,

so the target column name is expressed by the **value** of this variable.

And a remark about the comment by *Chris90*:

If you write *df.loc[df['column_name'] == '1-5','Minutes']*
you will get a **single** value from:

- row containing *1-5* (*string*) in *column_name*,
- *Minutes* column.

But you wrote that you wanted **all values** from this column.

Comment: I am confused, when I run code: df.loc[df['column_name'] == '0-5','minutes']

This seems to give me all values from minutes column that have a value of 0-5 for column name column not  a single value

Comment: The first expression between brackets (*df['column_name'] == '0-5'*)
gives a *boolean* Series with *True* values if *column_name* has
particular value. The result is that you get values from **all**
such rows. Read about indexing in Pandas.

Answer (score 1):

Do you want the returned value to be something simpler than dataframe or series like:

```
[19,11]
```

this?

Then use tolist() method like this:

```
df.loc[df['column_name'] == "1-5"]["Minutes"].tolist()
```

Comment: I want the returned values to be something that can be plotted,  was @user3508066 answer above not correct?  ( df.loc[df['column_name'] == '1-5','Minutes )?

Comment: Yes that was also correct. Are you facing any issue when plotting?